Unable to use VARs from a tfvars file in Terraform
I am new in Terraform. I am trying to setup some scripts for managing Cisco Catalyst Center (new name of Cisco DNA, but I am using the DNA Provider anyway :) ). I used an existing repo, that I've modified.
I have structure that looks like this:
├── main.tf
├── variables.tf
├── modules 
│ └── site_settings 
│   └── site.tf 
│   └── variables.tf
├── Site-1
│ └── site-1.tfvars

In ./main.tf I have:
provider "dnacenter" {

    username = var.dnac_username
    password = var.dnac_password
    base_url = var.dnac_url
    debug = "true"
    ssl_verify = "false"
}

module "site_settings" {
  # Using m0_general_settings module to configure general settings
  source = "../modules/site_settings"

  dnac_username = var.dnac_username
  dnac_password = var.dnac_password
  dnac_url = var.dnac_url

  global_name = var.global_name
  region_name = var.region_name
  country_name = var.country_name
  city_name = var.city_name
  site_name = var.site_name
  buildings = var.buildings
  building_name = var.building_name
}

The ./modules/site_settings/site.tf has:
resource "dnacenter_area" "country" {
    provider = dnacenter
    parameters {
      site {
        area {
          name = var.country_name
          parent_name = "${var.global_name}/${var.region_name}"
        }
      }
    type = "area"
    }
  }
  
  resource "dnacenter_area" "city" {
    depends_on = [ dnacenter_area.country ]
    provider = dnacenter
    parameters {
      site {
        area {
          name = var.city_name
          parent_name = "${var.global_name}/${var.region_name}/${var.country_name}"
        }
      }
    type = "area"
    }
  }
  
  resource "dnacenter_area" "site" {
    depends_on = [ dnacenter_area.city ]
    provider = dnacenter
    parameters {
      site {
        area {
          name = var.site_name
          parent_name = "${var.parent_name}/${var.global_name}/${var.country_name}/${var.city_name}"
        }
      }
    type = "area"
    }
  }
  
**  resource "dnacenter_building" "building" {
    depends_on = [ dnacenter_area.site ]
    for_each = { for building in var.buildings : building.name => building }
    provider = dnacenter
    parameters {
      site {
        building {
          name        = "${each.value.building_name}"
          parent_name = "${var.global_name}/${var.region_name}/${var.country_name}/${var.city_name}/${each.value.parent_site_name}"
          latitude    = "${each.value.latitude}"
          longitude   = "${each.value.longitude}"
        }
      }
    type = "building"
    }
  }**

These are the varialbe values in ./site-1.tfvars :
dnac_username = "Cisco"
dnac_password = "Cisco123"
dnac_url = "https://my-dna-lab.test.net"
global_name = "Global"
region_name = "EMEA"
country_name = "Spain"
city_name = "Madrid"
site_name = "Site-1"
buildings = [
{
building_name = "B01"
parent_site_name = "Site-1"
latitude = "xx.xxxx"
longitude = "xx.xxxx"
},
{
building_name = "B02"
parent_site_name = "Site-1"
latitude = "xx.xxxx"
longitude = "xx.xxxx"
},
]

The variables are defined in both ./variables.tf and ./modules/site_settings/variables.tf ... not sure why :) :
variable "dnac_username" {
    sensitive = true
}
variable "dnac_password" {
    sensitive = true
}
variable "dnac_url" {
  type = string
}
variable "global_name" {
  type = string
}
variable "region_name" {
  type = string
}
variable "country_name" {
  type = string
}
variable "city_name" {
  type = string
}
variable "site_name" {
  type = string
}
variable "building_name" {
  type = string
}
variable "parent_site_name" {
  type = string
}

I have the variables.tf in the root and in the subfolder, not quite sure why .... but regardless if I keep them in only one of those I am still asked for the variables, even though I specify I want to use the ones from the site-1.tfvars file:
   ~/Doc/G/ccc  on   main ?1  terraform plan -out Site-1/site-1.tfplan **-var-file=Site-1/site-1.tfvars**
**var.building_name
  Enter a value: **


I would expect not to be asked for the variables defined in the tfvars file, I guess something is wrong with how variables are set/formatted in that tfvars file, or with my loop for the building. Can you please help? :) Thanks!

I have the variables.tf in the root and in the subfolder, not quite sure why - each module (root module or submodule) needs its own variables.

Please edit your post and show us both variables.tf files.

Hi Rui, both variables.tf files have the same content. After the comment from Thanh (below) I've replaced this:
variable "building_name" {
type = string
}
with:
variable "buildings" {
description = "List of buildings"
type = list(object({
building_name    = string
parent_site_name = string
latitude         = number
longitude        = number
}))
}

You should define ./variables.tf and ./modules/site_settings/variables.tf as a list, look like this:
variable "buildings" {
  description = "List of buildings"
  type = list(object({
    building_name    = string
    parent_site_name = string
    latitude         = string
    longitude        = string
  }))
}

Because of this :
parameters {
      site {
        building {
          name        = "${each.value.building_name}"
          parent_name = "${var.global_name}/${var.region_name}/${var.country_name}/${var.city_name}/${each.value.parent_site_name}"
          latitude    = "${each.value.latitude}"
          longitude   = "${each.value.longitude}"
        }
      }
    type = "building"
    }

And you provided a list:
buildings = [
 {
  building_name = "B01"
  parent_site_name = "Site-1"
  latitude = "xx.xxxx"
  longitude = "xx.xxxx"
 },
 {
  building_name = "B02"
  parent_site_name = "Site-1"
  latitude = "xx.xxxx"
  longitude = "xx.xxxx"
 },
]


Thanks Thanh, that helped! What i did is, I added that building var as you described (lat and long are numbers) in the room vars file. In the vars file under modules folder I left it only as 'variable "buildings" {}' and i've removed all objects (building_name, parent_site_name, ...) from both variable files. I am now facing another error which i am trying to fix, if i can't i will post more details here.

If this resolved your issue, can you mark it right answer, and post new question for another issues

This was fixed by adding the building var as described by Thanh  in the root vars file (lat and long are numbers).
In the vars file under modules folder I left it only as
'variable "buildings" {}'
and i've removed all objects (building_name, parent_site_name, ...) from both variable files.
